# Passing parameters/values from Emacs to external application

Tags: windows, emacs

I'm working on a plugin for a very niche CAD application that our company uses. The development environment is entirely based on Emacs and everything should be done through it.

In this case, code should be edited, navigated, compiled and debugged using Emacs. There is no separation from Emacs and the actual language compiler (from what we know so far - there is no compiler.exe).

Since my team is not a fan of Emacs we are trying to get rid of this dependency so we can use whatever editor we want an compile/interact with the application without Emacs, but looks like this is very hard because everything is built inside it, even go-to definition, find all references all and sorts of commands.

These are all defined in hundreds of .el files (LISP) that are called using custom commands from Emacs.

However, when calling "Run this file" for example, said file is ran inside the application and correctly executed so my question is: what mechanisms could be used used for this to happen? I don't expect precise answers as I can't share the name of the actual CAD application or anything else, but it would be really helpful to understand what options are possible so I can investigate them.

In summary, whenever I "Run this file" the actual application is started by Emacs by calling the command line and the actual file gets executed inside the application. Looks like the contents of the Emacs buffer are passed to the application somehow. This "how" is what I'm trying to find.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If "*the development environment is entirely based on Emacs and everything should be done through it*" then a good thing would be for your team to learn Emacs and Emacs Lisp, instead of remaining in the sorry state where it "*is not a fan of Emacs*" and "*trying to get rid*" of using Emacs. Either that or (it sounds like) you get to rewrite everything.

Comment: Look at the source code to see how "*the contents of the Emacs buffer are passed to the application*". You don't show any code, so that's up to you. So far, the question is likely to be closed as too broad or unclear.

Comment: A simple call to `shell-command-on-region` would be a trivial possibility, but there are more intricate options. You can start reading in the manual at `C-h i g` `(elisp) Processes`